# The probability that a device doesn't work during specific time interval

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Assume both the time to failure and time to repair are exponentially distributed. The failure rate is $\lambda$ and the repair rate is $\mu$. The repair starts immediately after the failure occurs. We use two random variables, $T_{up}$ and $T_{down}$, to represent the uptime and downtime of the device, respectively. Therefore, the density functions of these two random variables are as follows:

$f_{T_{up}}(t)=\lambda e^{-\lambda t}$

$f_{T_{down}}(t)=\mu e^{-\mu t}$

We use $T$ to represent the recovery time, where $T=T_{up}+T_{down}$. We also assume $T_{up}$ and $T_{down}$ are independent. Now I want to calculate the following probability:

$P(T_{up}<t_{k},T>t_{k+1})=P(T>t_{k+1}\mid T_{up}<t_{k})P(T_{up}<t_{k})$

Actually, $P(T_{up}<t_{k})$ is easy to derive, but how to calculate $P(T>t_{k+1}\mid T_{up}<t_{k})$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$P(T_u\lt t,\,t+s\lt T_u+T_d)=\int_0^tP(T_d\gt t+s-x)\,\mathrm dP_{T_u}(x)=\int_0^t \mathrm e^{-\mu(t+s-x)}\,\lambda \mathrm e^{-\lambda x}\,\mathrm dx=\cdots$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am a little confused about the derivation in the middle. Could you tell me more about the derivation of $P(T_u<t,t+s<T_u+T_d)=\int_{0}^{t}P(T_d>t+s-x)dP_{T_u}(x)$ ?

Comment: $$P(T_u+T_d\gt t+s\mid T_u=x)=P(T_d\gt t+s-x)$$

Comment: I got it. Thanks!